# Taking average of all files which meets a criterion in Python

Tags: python, list, python-os

I am trying to identify `.txt` files by scanning every folder which meets a criterion i.e. minimum of the file is less than half of the maximum of that file and then take the average of all these files which satisfy this criterion. But right now, it is taking average of all the non-empty files in the folder. How do I achieve this?

```
import os

NFILES=3

values = [[] for _ in range(NFILES)]

for i in range(NFILES):
    filepath = rf"C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\Trials\{i+1}\Test.txt"
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        with open(filepath) as data:
            lines = data.readlines()
            numbers = [int(line.strip()) for line in lines if line.strip().isdigit()]
            values[i].extend(numbers)
            if(min(values[i])<=0.5*max(values[i])):
                print(values[i])
            
valid_values = [v for v in values if v] 

for t in zip(*valid_values):
    with open(rf"C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Surfactant A-D\Trials\Averaged.txt", 'a') as f:
        f.writelines('\n')
        f.write(str(sum(t) // len(t)))
```

Comment: Maybe put `values[i].extend(numbers)` inside the `if` statement that checks the criteria?

Comment: I tried it and getting an error: ```in <module>
    if(min(values[i])<=0.5*max(values[i])):

ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence```.

Comment: You should check `min(numbers)` and `max(numbers)` in the `if` statement.

Comment: This works! Is it also possible file numbers which meet this criterion?

Comment: Just do `print(i)` to get the file number.

Comment: I mean I want to print the file numbers which meet the criterion. Using ```print(i)``` just gives me the total number of files.

Comment: If you put `print(i)` inside the `if` statement it will only print the numbers that meet the criterion.